# Why are my pictures opening but not saving to computer?

Tags: error, compactflash

I am in a bit of a pickle and am hoping someone can help me find the way out. I took about 600 or so pictures on a 32GB compact flash card on my vacation, but noticed something strange happening. As I took pictures, at some point, other pictures started getting deleted. This was strange, so I stopped using the card, hoping to preserve the images that were remaining on the card. Upon plugging in my card, I can see the files that were deleted, and I'm not so worried about them, but I am worried about the images that I can open in Preview, but that will not copy to my computer. I get an -36 error, which I researched, but have not found out how this can be resolved.

So my question is this - If I can see my photos in Preview, they must not be deleted, but why can I not save them to my computer, and how can I get them to save to my computer. So far, I have been able to save about half of my images, but would like all of them.

Comment: Have you copied files *to* this card? Have you seen https://kb.sandisk.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/9699/~/mac-error-code-36-when-transferring-files

Comment: What is "Preview"?

Comment: Preview is the macOS default viewer for pretty much anything text or picture-based.

Comment: How certain are you that the card is truly a 32GB card? Fight Flash Fraud app [F3X](https://github.com/insidegui/F3X) can test it, but I wouldn't until after you've either recovered the images or exhausted all possibilities. It's not meant to be destructive, but better safe than sorry.

Comment: Hey all, thank you for your input. I ended up running "first aid" on the flash card in Disk Utility and that seems to have solved the problem. The deleted files are still gone, but I was able to transfer the files still there to my machine.

Answer (score 4):

> If I can see my photos in Preview, they must not be deleted,

It sounds like your memory card is failing. Preview may be showing you thumbnails from the files which do not require the entire file to be read. Then, when you try to copy the entire file, it turns out there is a read error.